# Getting access to the Google Pay API for Passes

Tags: api, google-pay

I am currently trying to get access to the Google Pay API for passes. I am following the official guide provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api

Unfortunately I can't even follow the first step, as the sign up form for Google Merchant seems to be offline. The URL where I expect the form just forwards me to an FAQ page.
Has anyone had similar issues lately.

Any kind of help or information is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you work your way through this form completing contact options section? https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/gethelp?visit_id=1-636549173956235486-3194546471&rd=4

Comment: Hi Soc, thanks for your answer. Am I missing something? This URL only shows me an faq page with some information about the service. But there is no form...

Answer (score 1):

Moving discussion from comment to answer to include image.

Hard to say if we're seeing the same thing. This is what I see when visiting https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/gethelp?visit_id=1-636549173956235486-3194546471&rd=4

[image]

Is this what you see?

Comment: Hey Soc, thanks for your support. I was finally able to figure it out. I got to the form you showed here and was able to submit my request. For explanation (if anyone else gets into a similar situation): I think the problem was, that I was trying to access these services from germany (I hope this is a temporary issue). I was always redirected to the faq page. I accessed the url from a US based proxy server and was able to reach the form afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go straight to step 2. Access the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: The user must have a pay account to do the second step that require he being logged in.